# Issue in passing function in matchDispatchToProps -- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Iam creating a Dropdown list in react-redux and saving the selected state of the Dropdown to use the that value in my App.

But while creating a call for action function, Iam stuck and can store the value required:

*RoleReducer which has the json object*

**RoleReducer.js**

```
export default function () {
    return [
        {
            key:1,
            value: "abc"
        },
        {
            key:2,
            value: "def"
        },
        {
            key:3,
            value: "hij"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Action component where the selected dropdown will be saved*

**selectedRoleAction.js**

```
const selectedRoleAction = (role) => {
    console.log("role selected is: ",  role.key);
    return {
        type: "ROLE_SELECTED",
        payload: role,
    }
};

export default selectedRoleAction;
```

*Component where the dropdown is created and the actions will be used*

**RoleDropDown.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ActionsReducer from '../../../reducers/actionsReducer';
import rolesReducer from '../../../reducers/rolesReducer';
import selectedRoleAction from '../../../actions/selectedRoleAction';
import ActionsActions from '../../../actions/actionsActions';

class RoleDropdown extends Component {
    
    createDropdownlist() {
        return this.props.roles.map((role) => {
            return (
                <option value={role.value}>{role.value}</option>
                
            )
        })}

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <select
                    onChange={() => this.props.selectedRoleAction(role)}
                    className="form-control">
                    <option>Please select a role</option>
                    {this.createDropdownlist()}
                    </select>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        roles: state.roles,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({selectedRoleAction:selectedRoleAction}, dispatch)
  }
  

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(withRouter(RoleDropdown));
```

*The error in output*

**Error**

```
Failed to compile
./src/containers/MainContent/Dashboard/RoleDropdown.js
  Line 36:  'role' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: the issue is not with your mapDispatchToprops it with your `onChange={() => this.props.selectedRoleAction(role)}` . where are you getting this `role` from ?

Comment: From "selectedRoleAction.js", there i want to save the selected option("role") from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error message it says `role` is not defined .

selecting an option in `select` will fire `onChange` with the `selectedOption` as your first argument. so you need to change your code as

```
onChange={(role) => this.props.selectedRoleAction(role)}
```

You were trying to pass the `role` which as not there that's why the error message hinted you saying `'role' is not defined  no-undef` as it was not able to find the `role` .